# Multiple different Detail View in UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, swift, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, detailview

I would like to make an **universal app** like settings app of iPad with the `UISplitViewController`.

Then, the Master View of `UISplitViewController` 'fixed' with `UITableView` and the **detail view** with different view and `UINavigationController`.

I want that the **detail view** can have a **multiple segue**.

Can anybody tell me how to set up the storyboard and the code (Swift) ?

Comment: You will get more useful help here for development problems rather than thinking of it as a coding service.  I suggest starting with the master/detail template and then asking for help about specific issues that give you trouble.

Comment: I already started, only that I wanted an "initial" opinion to fix my current project. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499141/second-segue-of-uisplitviewcontroller-not-show-back-button-on-ipad-but-on-iphone)